# Error: 'Apps aren't load yet' when i try to import a model from another python project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to use a model from another python project to store data in django database. So, a create an another python file, which runs continuously, inside directory of other django files. The files structure are show bellow

```
ProjectFolder
     WebSite
         operation
         urls.py
         views.py
         models.py
         admin.py
         apps.py
     db.sqlite3
     manage.py
     pythonserver.py
```

In my pythonserver.py i try to do:

```
import os, sys
if os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','WebSite.settings'):
    from WebSite.operation.models import Registers
else:
    raise
    sys.exit(1)
```

The execution returns: "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

I'm using django 1.11

What is wrong? What the best pratice to use a model from other python file/project?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

I django 1.11 it's necessary executes setup() method from django. Then the sintax is:

```
if os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'WebSite.settings'):
    import django
    django.setup()
    from WebSite.operation.models import Registers
    from django.utils import timezone
else:
    raise
    sys.exit(1)
```